# Android libraries for transit schedule

Tags: android, sdk

[image]

Which library is used to design this UI, Or is there any built in view in Android for the same

Answer (score 0):

What part of this task exactly is a problem for you?

It is easy to create current view using RecyclerView, for example.

(To use it add:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

in your app's build.gradle file.)

When making all transit way (bunch of dots and lines), if you use RecyclerView,
every single item can contain it's dot and two vertical lines upper and below the dot. When they are placed one below another it will look like your picture.

Next question is how to make this lines with dots.
There some ways:

1. The simpliest on is to make a `.png` file in your favourite program (Photo shop, Adobe Illustrator, Figma, Sketch if using MAC or whatever you like).
2. Make a custom view and draw this lines and circle in onDraw method.
3. Make drawable xml file
4. Other simple way (if ways above are too difficult for you) is to add 3 ImageViews in the vertical LinearLayout: first for the upper line, second for the dot, third for line below dot and put related images in each ImageView.

Do you still have problems to implement your view?

Comment: The vertical lines with dots?